# How to create Apple MediaPlayerController on Android MusicKit

Tags: android, sdk, playback, apple-music

I am creating an Android app with uses the Apple Music SDK. When creating the MediaPlayerController I get the following error:

No implementation found for int com.apple.android.music.foothill.javanative.FootHillConfig.config(java.lang.String)

With the following Code:

```java
public class AppleMusicPlaybackFunctions {
    private MediaPlayerController playerController;
    private CatalogPlaybackQueueItemProvider.Builder queueProviderBuilder;
    private AppleMusicTokenProvider appleMusicTokenProvider;


    public AppleMusicPlaybackFunctions(Context context, AppleMusicTokenProvider appleMusicTokenProvider) {
        this.playerController = MediaPlayerControllerFactory.createLocalController(context, appleMusicTokenProvider);
        this.queueProviderBuilder = new CatalogPlaybackQueueItemProvider.Builder();
        this.appleMusicTokenProvider = appleMusicTokenProvider;

        playerController.addListener(this);
    }


    public void playPause() {
        if (playerController.getPlaybackState() == PlaybackState.PLAYING){
            playerController.pause();
        } else {
            playerController.play();
        }
    }
}
```

The user already has logged in to Apple Music, the AppleMusicTokenProvider returns the user token of the current user and the apple developer token.

Are there other steps you must take before you can playback?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you found any solution to this?

Comment: Do you found any solution to this? I am stuck because of this error

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're missing a few libraries. Add the libraries below:

```
System.loadLibrary("c++_shared")
System.loadLibrary("appleMusicSDK")
```